# How to make an item template, which would be available on all project types

Tags: visual-studio, templates, vsix

I am making a Visual Studio extension, which allows to embed web pages into your projects and solutions: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/52bd30dd-596f-40a9-94a9-ba3fb250c671

Alpha is out. However, I have a problem: item template for a web page link indeed appears in File -> 'New -> File ...' dialog, but not when I do right click on C# project, and select 'New Item ...' there. I understand, that I can add identical template to ItemTemplates folder, specific to C# projects, but I want my template be easily available in all project types via 'New Item ...'.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the item templates to display all the projects you need to create the  Custom item templates like Custom project system.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.